# Concatenate multiple commands

Tags: java, regex

How can I manipulate this regular expression

```
String oneCmd = "([0-9]+\\.[tcm]{1}\\#.+\\#[wsn]{1})";
```

to avoid matching

```
"100.m#testValue#w100.m#testValue#w"
```

but allow matching

```
100.m#testValue#w
```

? Because in the end I want that there can be multiple commands separated by `|`

```
String regex = "^(" + oneCmd + "$|" + oneCmd + "\\|{1}" + oneCmd + "$)";
```

so that valid commands are:

```
cmd
cmd|cmd1|cmd2|... not ending with an '|' !!
```

but the first problem is that if I just concatenate 2 or more commands it is still valid.

Comment: If your string looks like `cmd1cmd2|cmd3|cmd4`, what should happen - no match at all, or match only `cmd3` and `cmd4`, ignoring `cmd1cmd2`?

Comment: Just ignoreing all of them, because they will be parsed and executed afterwards and all commands are necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most readable way would be to first split on `|` and then apply a regex that only allows one match:

```
^[0-9]+\\.[tcm]#[^#]*#[wsn]$
```

If you want to find matches that are separated by `|` and/or the start/end of the string, you can do that with [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of `^` and `$` anchors:

```
(?<=^|\\|)[0-9]+\\.[tcm]#[^#]*#[wsn](?=$|\\|)
```

Comment: your first approach works fine, but the second doesn't. But I wil use your first annyway, because it is easier to understand

Comment: could you explain what you mean with #[^#] in your first approach? Is it just 'any string starting with #'? but why is then '##' not valid?

Comment: `[^#]*` matches any number of characters except `#`. If I had used `.*` in there, it would also have matched the delimiting `#` characters if there was more than one command in the string.